# Graphviz and Matlab - 'dot' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: matlab, path, installation, graphviz

I've just installed Graphviz and update the environment variable PATH properly.
The problem is that when I try to use Graphviz with Matlab, this error occurs:

*dot is not recognized as an internal or external command*.

Can you help me?

Comment: I haven't used Graphviz so I may be wrong here, but "when I try to use Graphviz with Matlab" seems unclear. Are you running a system command from Matlab?

Comment: What happens when you star dot from a terminal session? Do you start matlab from a terminal session or through a shortcut? in the later case probably login again.

Comment: Please complete your question: what OS are we talking about here? How did you install Graphviz? Can you run `dot` from a command line? How are you trying to run `dot` from within MATLAB?